# Deployed Steroid.js app not appearing in AppGyver Could Services

Tags: html, cordova, build, phonegap-build, steroids

I am building a Steroid.js/PhoneGap App. I have successfully installed steroids CLI on my computer and am able to create steroids projects using the command.

steroids build {project_name}

My app requires Facebook Auth which I'm trying to implement via the Steroids [integrated Facebook Plugin (ios) guide](http://guides.appgyver.com/steroids/guides/phonegap_on_steroids/facebook-connect-plugin/). As per the instructions I am able to generate a QR code for my app using the command

```
steroids connect
```

Once I scan the QR code with the AppGyver scanner app I am able to update the deploy app via the command

```
steroids deploy
```

But when I go to [AppGyver Cloud Services](https://cloud.appgyver.com/applications) as per the instructions in [deploying to cloud services](http://guides.appgyver.com/steroids/guides/steroids_npm/cloud-deploy/) it says.

```
You have not built any of your apps to the AppGyver Cloud yet
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hey, AppGyver employee here!

Do you get a link to a http://share.appgyver.com URL after `steroids deploy`? Is a `cloud.json` file generated? Can you try `steroids logout` and `steroids login`?

If the cloud deploy succeeds but you still can't see the app, the only idea that comes to mind is that you're logged in as a different user in AppGyver Cloud and Steroids. If that's not the case, post more details here and we'll dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

As harsa_ suggested,

simply logging in the correct account should fix this issue.

Simply run

```
steroids logout
```

and then

```
steroids login
```

and everything should work correctly. The two main reasons this happens is because you're either:

1) Logged in in another account

2) You're not logged in